# Would you recommend C++ Coding Standard by Todd Hoff?

Tags: c++, coding-style

Hallo

at the moment I am looking for a good C++ coding standards, which I can stick with. In internet I could find a lot of coding standards. Some rules are common in most of them. But there are also differences. 
I found C++ Coding Standard by Todd Hoff (http://www.maultech.com/chrislott/resources/cstyle/CppCodingStandard.html). I took a look and found it really great. He gave not only some common rules, but also went into the details. Good example is Name Convention.

I would like to know, if someone use this C++ coding standards and would he recommend to use it or not?

Comment: I don't know it specifically. But, FYI, [the books I recommend are listed here](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources). There may be a reason that Hoff is not on that list.

Comment: Thank you for the list. :-) Maybe you are right, there should be a reason, why Hoff is not on the list. But it's also interesting what this reason is. :-)

Comment: Asking a large audience whether they would recommend a particular coding standard is going to solicit highly subjectvie answers. Indeed, coding standard preferences are just about the most subjective topic I can think of amongst developers. I would suggest choosing something that improves the readability of your code, and to apply it consistently to your code base, with a pinch of pragmatism thrown in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding Hoff:

**Horrendous naming conventions**
The naming conventions are very non-standard. In most places I have worked and most conventions I have looked at, member functions and member data follow the same rule: All lower case, words separated by underscores.

Those InitialCaps identifiers are hard to read, even for the sighted. There have been multiple human factors studies on this. WordsSeparatedByInitialCaps is much harder for people to read that is words_separated_by_underscores. For the visually impaired, use of InitialCaps is worse than worthless. In the coding standards over which I have influence, InitialCaps are for class names, and class names only.

ALL_CAPS is even harder to read than InitialCaps. Every legal contract has some truly important legal clause that lawyers would prefer that we gloss over and ignore. Those important clauses are easy to find: THEY ARE IN ALL CAPS. Text in all caps is extremely hard to read for the sighted. That is why lawyers like to use it. We should eschew ALL_CAPS as much as possible. Reserve ALL_CAPS for macros only, and never define a macro that is not ALL_CAPS. This minimizes the collisions between proprocessor names and identifiers.

And Hungarian notation sucks, even if it is only partially used in part.

**Violates RAII**
The standards violate RAII. To wit (emphasis mine):

> Do not do any real work in an object's constructor. Inside a constructor initialize variables only and/or do only actions that can't fail. Create an Open() method for an object which completes construction. *Open() should be called after object instantiation*.

**Very bad advice on destructors**
The advice on destructors is just as bad as the advice on constructors.

> Be Careful Throwing Exceptions in Destructors

Really? How about 'Don't throw exceptions in destructors.'

More from this section,

> Special care must be taken to catch exceptions which may occur during object destruction. Special care must also be taken to fully destruct an object when it throws an exception.

And how exactly is someone going to do that? The simple answer is the right one: Don't throw exceptions in a destructor. Ever.

**This is truly hideous**

```
/////////////////////////////// PUBLIC ///////////////////////////////////////

//============================= LIFECYCLE ====================================

XX::XX()
{
}// XX

XX::XX(const XX&)
{
}// XX

XX::~XX()
{
}// ~XX


//============================= OPERATORS ====================================

XX& 
XX::operator=(XX&);
{
   return *this;

}// =

//============================= OPERATIONS ===================================
//============================= ACESS      ===================================
//============================= INQUIRY    ===================================
/////////////////////////////// PROTECTED  ///////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////// PRIVATE    ///////////////////////////////////
```

**That stupid (6 == errorNum) garbage**
I hate that construct. It is ugly and puts the horse before the cart. The right thing to do here is to require that the code compile clean under -Wall or stricter conditions and to use a code analyzer that catches additional problems that the compiler can't/won't find. Don't make me write things bass ackwards because twenty years ago some idiot wrote `if (errorNum = 6) ...`.

**The Bull of Boolean Types**
The title of this section is correct: It's bull. What he wrote is outdated and wrong. If you are writing new code, use bool. If you are maintaining old code, don't change it unless it needs to be changed.

His advice not to compare booleans to true is correct. The solution is not to compare booleans to false (or even worse `if (FALSE != func()) ...`). The solution is not to compare booleans to anything: `if (func()) ...`.

**The problems with this standard go on and on.**
So don't use it.

Comment: @jk: Fixed. Thanks. I'm dyslexic at times.

Answer (score 7):

Taking a quick glance through it, it looks OK on most things. The one thing that caught my eye as something I don't really agree with are some of the naming conventions he proposes in there, but the concept of having a consistent way to name things is dead on.

Another resource you might want to look at is *C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices* by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu. Its not as concrete as Todd Hoff's but it does provide more discussion on why the specific rule should be a part of your coding standard.

Comment: Thank you. I also found that a lot of people recommended this book. :-) (I think, I will buy this book.) For example, I don't like to use upper-case naming convention for function, like it was suggested in standard by Todd Hoff. But it's just small changes that I can apply to this standard.

Comment: Sutter & Alexandrescu's rule #0 ("Don't sweat the small stuff") is particularly important. Too many projects violate this rule in their coding standards.

Comment: A style guide that says "Do Not do Real Work in Object Constructors" and therefore frowns upon RAII can't be a good style guide. RAII is one of the most central concepts of common C++ practice and the standard library. -1, just for the sorting.